# How to run @Configuration just after ContextRefreshEvent?

Tags: java, spring, configuration

How can I make a `@Configuration` run after the `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` component?

I run some database insertions with the ApplicationListener, but in the @Configuration I need the data generated with those insertions.

I tryed `@AuthConfgureAfter`, `@DependsOn` and `@Order` but still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "run" @Configuration? What do you have in your configuration class that depends on the ContextRefreshEvent? Please add some details, that will help to give a good answer.

Comment: Ok. I edited the post.

Comment: `@Configuration` defines Spring beans. `ContextRefreshedEvent` is emitted when all beans have been configured and the application is ready. Therefore `@Configuration` cannot be triggered *after* `ContextRefreshedEvent`. It would help if you elaborated on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Perhaps the beans that need the data can listen for the `ContextRefreshedEvent` themselves and update their internal state?

Comment: I'm trying to run some sort of InitialDataLoader prior to Jobs(Quartz) to start. Some of the data used on the jobs are inserted at the dataLoader execution. Btw, it would not suit to put that on a script because it need to go through some rules of the business layer when inserting, it would became exausting to do it like this.